Camera follow path counterclockwise
I’m trying to do a simple camera rotation around an object - but somehow I can't get the camera to go counterclockwise. 
Here is my set-up:
I created a curve circle around the object
I parented my camera to the curve circle with Follow path
Now the camera is moving around my object as it should. But it is moving clockwise. I need it to go counterclockwise. How do I do it? It seems like a simple task, but I can't for the life of me get it to work. Any suggestions? Thank you in advance for your help.

Stupid question on my behalf: do you need to use a curve? Parenting the camera to an empty in the center and making this rotate can get you the same result and there you can even switch the direction anytime you want in the animation...

@GordonBrinkmann thank you. I didn’t know that. Going to try it right away.

I agree with Gordon that using an Empty would be easier in this case.

@JohnEason I just tried this method and found it less versatile than working with Follow path, because I am additionally using Track To. A mix of Follow path, Track To and Empties works best, in my humble opinion. 1000 thanks to both of you.

It's also useful to know about that setting if you're just following a path rather than a circle. It's also helpful to show the curve normal direction in Edit mode. In Blender 4+, look to the right of old Viewport Overlays and find the new menu Curve Edit Mode Overlays. Check the Normals entry on that dropdown. In earlier versions it's at the bottom of the View Overlays dropdow.

For a simple rotation an empty as parent is the easiest way I'd say. Don't know what you meant with "because I am additionally using Track to"? You can use a Track to constraint on the camera even if it is only parented to an empty nevertheless. Of course if you want a different path than a circle then a curve might be better. But the question was just about a circle rotation ‍♂️

Go into Edit mode with your Circle selected, select All, and then use the Segments > SwitchDirection menu.


Thank you so much! You are a true boon.

Thank you again @JohnEason. This is very helpful information.

It depends on how you did it. You can of course switch the direction of the curve. Other ways include:

If you animated the camera by clicking on Animate Path in the Follow Path constraint, you can select the Bézier Circle and go to the Graph Editor. There go to Modifiers and change the value for Coefficient from -1 to 1 and the value for x^1 from 1 to -1 to make it go counter-clockwise.


If you instead animated the Offset value in the Follow Path constraint for some reason to go from 100 to 0, animate it the other way around from 0 to 100.


A different approach could be to simply parent the Camera to an Empty object and animate the rotation of the Empty in whatever direction you wish.




Thank you again @GordonBrinkmann. This is very helpful information.
